# Java : VolatileImage slower than BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, graphics, volatile

I'm making a game in java and in used BufferedImages to render content to the screen. I had performance issues on low end machines where the game is supposed to run, so I switched to VolatileImage which are normally faster. Except they actually slow the whole thing down.

The images are created with GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleVolatileImage(...) and are drawn to the screen with [Graphics.drawImage(...)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) (follow link to see which one specifically). They are drawn upon a Canvas using double buffering.

Does someone has an idea of what is going wrong here ?

Comment: I have noticed the same.

Comment: If you're short of memory on the graphics card, it obviously wont help. IIRC, `BufferedImage` has had some speedups, so the difference might not be as great as it once was.

Comment: @Norswap: I really think that to find a great answer to this consist in finding top-notch Open Source Java games (there surely are some) or some great great Java demo (from the "demo scene") and try to understand what they've done.  I used to program games and demos a long time ago on *very* exotic hardware (like the Amiga, SNES, mode 13x etc.) and I still don't know how to "push pixels" correctly in Java.  This is once more a domain where Java has been "overengineered" and is unnecessarily complicated.  I don't hold for my breath for someone here on SO to be able to really help you.

Comment: It's definitely not a problem of video memory (I only have 700kb worth of image to keep in memory). Also a friend of mine using VolatileImages in his own game (which he test on the same computers) said I saw a 10x speed improvement when switching from BufferedImages).

Answer (score 6):

Most likely your code is mixing accelerated and unaccelerated operations.

This [document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tsg-desktop-150005.pdf) is a must read. Section 3.2 in particular is essential for anyone working with accelerated Java graphics.

Comment: Is it possible that scaling (in the sense of clipping, see link in the question) an image is such an unaccelerated operation ? Since I use sprite sheets, every draw must effectively select a part of the image to draw to the screen.